# Symfony: question about get and set methods of the base model classes

Tags: model, symfony1

if you go to a base class of the model you won't find any get or set method.

It is because those methods is said are created "on the air".

What does it mean exacltly, I suspect it just means they are created in the moment they are needed.

Am i right? What are the advantages of the way rescpect of generate the methods inside the base class?

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine uses PHP's [magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) to implement, amongst other things, the `get*()` and `set*()` methods, so it will check to make sure the column exists, and if so, get or set the value accordingly.

In addition, Doctrine will also check to see if you have implemented your own individual get/set methods, eg `getSurname()` and use this in preference to just setting the column value directly.

Comment: This is essentially correct, but the magic happens in sfDoctrineRecord (a Symfony creation) not in Doctrine.

Answer (score 0):

richsage is correct that the `getXXX` and `setXXX` methods are done via PHP's "magic" `__call` method, but it is not Doctrine doing the magic. It is `sfDoctrineRecord::__call` that transforms an invocation like `$record->getName()` to `$record->get('name')`.